# What is the encoding for special characters in second level domains?

Tags: google-chrome, url, encoding, urlencode

I am wondering what is the encoding of second-level domains, because when I type in chrome something like this: xn--rvo-e3a.com it shows up like this: rvož.com. I can't find any answers on the internet.
Thanks
[image]

Comment: It's [punycode](https://www.name.com/punycode-converter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big thanks to @JosefZ as he said it's a punycode.